# Javascript - How pass function click, from one menu to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I am a beginner in JS (level 0.1), and I have a problem with my script.

My practice page has only 1 page, but 2 menus, and I need that when clicking on a menu, this click passes the `.active` class to the other brother button (1A to 1B, etc.). And I do not know how to do it.

My script works well **with one menu at a time**, but does not apply the `.active` class to the second menu.

**[SEE DEMO LIVE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eoqpbX)** (Codepen)

What am I doing wrong...?

Thanks in advance!

//----------------

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cont-menu .menu').click(function(){
    $('.menu').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

```css
body{text-align:center;font-family:Arial,sans-serif}.code{background:#d9d9d9;padding:2px 5px}#cont-menu span{line-height:1.75}#cont-menu{position:relative;width:500px;margin:0 auto;top:5px}#menu-1,#menu-2{width:150px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;margin:0 20px}.menu{padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;margin:0 0 3px 0;color:#fff;text-align:left;background:#999;cursor:pointer}.menu:hover{background:red}

.active{background:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cont-menu">
    <div id="menu-1">
      <div class="menu active">Buton 1-A</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 2-A</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 3-A</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 4-A</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 5-A</div>
    </div>

    <div id="menu-2">
      <div class="menu active">Buton 1-B</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 2-B</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 3-B</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 4-B</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 5-B</div>
    </div>
  <br><br>
<span>How to change the script so that when you click on the Menu on the left pass the <span class="code">.active</span> class also on the right, so that both buttons.<br>( 1A &rarr; 1B ... 2A &rarr; 2B ... 3A &rarr; 3B )<br>and vice versa, of course, are active at the same time...?</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a demo for you that works, and also documented step-by-step how the code works. ***If you have DevTools (F12) open in Chrome when you run the code***, it will stop at the `debugger;` directive and allow you to use F10 to step through the code line by line in the DevTools window.

Comment: Look at Felix Kling's answer - more elegant than mine (simpler, shorter) but also requires that the buttons are in the same position on both menus. +1 to Felix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cont-menu .menu').click(function(){
    $('.menu').removeClass('active');
    //Get the element from each list which matches the position of the clicked element
    $('#menu-1').children().eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
    $('#menu-2').children().eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWVoob)

Comment: Thanks **@wormania**. It is the solution that best suits me current development.

Answer (score 2):

If the buttons are simply associated by their position in the menu, we can get that position, and then select all elements at the same position in every menu (via the [`:nth-child` selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)). To make things easier we add a class to every menu.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cont-menu .menu').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('.menu').removeClass("active");
    $('.menu-container :nth-child('+index+')').addClass("active");
});
});
```

```css
body{text-align:center;font-family:Arial,sans-serif}.code{background:#d9d9d9;padding:2px 5px}#cont-menu span{line-height:1.75}#cont-menu{position:relative;width:500px;margin:0 auto;top:5px}#menu-1,#menu-2{width:150px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;margin:0 20px}.menu{padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;margin:0 0 3px 0;color:#fff;text-align:left;background:#999;cursor:pointer}.menu:hover{background:red}

.active{background:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cont-menu">
    <div class="menu-container">
      <div class="menu active">Buton 1-A</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 2-A</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 3-A</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 4-A</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 5-A</div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-container">
      <div class="menu active">Buton 1-B</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 2-B</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 3-B</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 4-B</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 5-B</div>
    </div>
  <br><br>
<span>How to change the script so that when you click on the Menu on the left pass the <span class="code">.active</span> class also on the right, so that both buttons.<br>( 1A &rarr; 1B ... 2A &rarr; 2B ... 3A &rarr; 3B )<br>and vice versa, of course, are active at the same time...?</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks **Felix Kling**. I will study your response in detail. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently only adding the `.active` class to the clicked button, if we add a identifier for each button (a name) we can achieve what you're asking.

Try:

```
$(`[name=${$(this).attr('name')}]`).addClass("active");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cont-menu .menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').removeClass("active");
    $(`[name=${$(this).attr('name')}]`).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif
}

.code {
  background: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 2px 5px
}

#cont-menu span {
  line-height: 1.75
}

#cont-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 5px
}

#menu-1,
#menu-2 {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 20px
}

.menu {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  background: #999;
  cursor: pointer
}

.menu:hover {
  background: red
}

.active {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont-menu">
  <div id="menu-1">
    <div class="menu active" name="button1">Buton 1-A</div>
    <div class="menu" name="button2">Buton 2-A</div>
    <div class="menu" name="button3">Buton 3-A</div>
    <div class="menu" name="button4">Buton 4-A</div>
    <div class="menu" name="button5">Buton 5-A</div>
  </div>

  <div id="menu-2">
    <div class="menu active" name="button1">Buton 1-B</div>
    <div class="menu" name="button2">Buton 2-B</div>
    <div class="menu" name="button3">Buton 3-B</div>
    <div class="menu" name="button4">Buton 4-B</div>
    <div class="menu" name="button5">Buton 5-B</div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks **John**. I will study your response in detail. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the jQuery data attribute. We set a value for this on each menu that associates it with 1-5, this can then be used to add the class for both menu buttons.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cont-menu .menu').click(function(){
    //get the value of the data-menu-class attribute
    var menuClass = $(this).data('menu-class');
    //remove all previous active classes
    $('.menu').removeClass("active");
    //add active to each menu (1&2)
    $('#menu-1 .menu'+menuClass).addClass('active');
    $('#menu-2 .menu'+menuClass).addClass('active');
});
});
```

```css
body{text-align:center;font-family:Arial,sans-serif}.code{background:#d9d9d9;padding:2px 5px}#cont-menu span{line-height:1.75}#cont-menu{position:relative;width:500px;margin:0 auto;top:5px}#menu-1,#menu-2{width:150px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;margin:0 20px}.menu{padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;margin:0 0 3px 0;color:#fff;text-align:left;background:#999;cursor:pointer}.menu:hover{background:red}

.active{background:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cont-menu">
    <div id="menu-1">
      <div class="menu menu1 active" data-menu-class='1'>Buton 1-A</div>
      <div class="menu menu2" data-menu-class='2'>Buton 2-A</div>
      <div class="menu menu3" data-menu-class='3'>Buton 3-A</div>
      <div class="menu menu4" data-menu-class='4'>Buton 4-A</div>
      <div class="menu menu5" data-menu-classx='5'>Buton 5-A</div>
    </div>

    <div id="menu-2">
      <div class="menu menu1 active" data-menu-class='1'>Buton 1-B</div>
      <div class="menu menu2" data-menu-class='2'>Buton 2-B</div>
      <div class="menu menu3" data-menu-class='3'>Buton 3-B</div>
      <div class="menu menu4" data-menu-class='4'>Buton 4-B</div>
      <div class="menu menu5" data-menu-class='5'>Buton 5-B</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks **aCMoFoCord**. I will study your response in detail. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some text manipulation to parse the IDs and button text values, in order to identify which button was clicked, from which menu, and then calculate how to find the same button in the *other* menu.

This demo's comments assumes you choose `Buton 3` from the first menu. The code will:

1. Traverse UP the DOM tree from the clicked button to find the closest wrapper *(Note that I added a class to both button wrappers to make that easy)*, and grab its ID.
2. Split the ID on the hyphen, then grab the right-side value (1 or 2)
3. Use a ternary operator to get the other number (i.e. if this is menu 1, `nxt_mnu` is 2, etc)
4. Get the text of this button
5. Same as (2) above, use `split()` to get just the text before the `-A` or `-B`
6. Remove `.active` class from all buttons on all menus
7. Add `.active` class to the clicked button
8. (a) Select the next menu, (b) find the button with text containing same text as the button clicked, (c) Add active class to that sister button

#### DEMO:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#cont-menu .menu').click(function(){
   debugger;
      let mnu_num = $(this).closest('.menu-wrapper').attr('id');
      mnu_num = mnu_num.split('-')[1]; //menu-1
      let nxt_mnu = (mnu_num == 1) ? '2' : '1'; //2
      let btn_txt = $(this).text(); //Buton 3-A
      btn_txt = btn_txt.split('-')[0] //eg. Buton 3
      $('.menu').removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $('#menu-' + nxt_mnu).find('.menu:contains(' +btn_txt+ ')').addClass('active');
   });
});
```

```css
body{text-align:center;font-family:Arial,sans-serif}.code{background:#d9d9d9;padding:2px 5px}#cont-menu span{line-height:1.75}#cont-menu{position:relative;width:500px;margin:0 auto;top:5px}#menu-1,#menu-2{width:150px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;margin:0 20px}.menu{padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;margin:0 0 3px 0;color:#fff;text-align:left;background:#999;cursor:pointer}.menu:hover{background:red}

.active{background:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cont-menu">
    <div id="menu-1" class="menu-wrapper">
      <div class="menu active">Buton 1-A</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 2-A</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 3-A</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 4-A</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 5-A</div>
    </div>

    <div id="menu-2" class="menu-wrapper">
      <div class="menu active">Buton 1-B</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 2-B</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 3-B</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 4-B</div>
      <div class="menu">Buton 5-B</div>
    </div>
  <br><br>
<span>How to change the script so that when you click on the Menu on the left pass the <span class="code">.active</span> class also on the right, so that both buttons.<br>( 1A &rarr; 1B ... 2A &rarr; 2B ... 3A &rarr; 3B )<br>and vice versa, of course, are active at the same time...?</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks **gibberish**. I will study your response in detail. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Here I use data attribute with css attribute selector to get the same element in the group. And to get same behaviour with hover effect, I use js to control it instead of css.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cont-menu').on('click', '.menu', function(e) {
    $('.menu').removeClass('active');
    $(`[data-group=${this.dataset.group}]`).addClass("active");
  });

  $('#cont-menu').on('mouseenter', '.menu', function(e) {
    $('.menu').removeClass('hover');
    $(`[data-group=${this.dataset.group}]`).addClass('hover')

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif
}

.code {
  background: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 2px 5px
}

#cont-menu span {
  line-height: 1.75
}

#cont-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 5px
}

#menu-1,
#menu-2 {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 20px
}

.menu {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  background: #999;
  cursor: pointer
}

.menu.hover {
  background: red;
}

.active {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cont-menu">
  <div id="menu-1">
    <div data-group="a" class="menu active">Buton 1-A</div>
    <div data-group="b" class="menu">Buton 2-A</div>
    <div data-group="c" class="menu">Buton 3-A</div>
    <div data-group="d" class="menu">Buton 4-A</div>
    <div data-group="e" class="menu">Buton 5-A</div>
  </div>

  <div id="menu-2">
    <div data-group="a" class="menu active">Buton 1-B</div>
    <div data-group="b" class="menu">Buton 2-B</div>
    <div data-group="c" class="menu">Buton 3-B</div>
    <div data-group="d" class="menu">Buton 4-B</div>
    <div data-group="e" class="menu">Buton 5-B</div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <span>How to change the script so that when you click on the Menu on the left pass the <span class="code">.active</span> class also on the right, so that both buttons.<br>( 1A &rarr; 1B ... 2A &rarr; 2B ... 3A &rarr; 3B )<br>and backwards, of course,
  are active at the same time...?</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks **Jabob**. I will study your response in detail. Greetings.